# Unable to detect bluetooth devices with windows 8.1 laptop using bluetoothview

Tags: windows, laptop, bluetooth, acer-aspire

I am using a tool called **bluetoothview** (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_viewer.html) on my Acer Aspire VN7-791 Laptop with Intel Wireless Bluetooth Adapter under Microsoft Windows 8.1 (x64) Build 9600. Bluetooth driver is installed.

The mentioned tool should detect all nearby devices that have bluetooth enabled, such as my Nexus-Tablet (Android 5.0) for example. The problem is that the list in the tool window remains empty, that is to say that **no devices are detected**. No error message appears when using the tool, so I dont know where to start looking for a solution.

I used the bluetooth interface on my tablet before successfully, but it is the first time I try to use bluetooth on my laptop. The Device Association Service (as mentioned in a related question) and the Bluetooth Support Service are enabled and running.

**Do you have any idea how to enable the laptop to detect bluetooth devices?**

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Bluetooth via the Charms Menu solved the problem:

http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26607/~/how-do-i-turn-bluetooth-and-wifi-on-and-off-in-windows-8%3F